# python script to find the unique value

Tags: python

I have a script to find the unique value from 2 files

`1.csv`

```
11 12 13 14    
21 22 23 24    
11 32 33 34
```

`2.csv`

```
41 42 43 44 45    
51 52 53 54 55    
41 62 63 64 65
```

script is:

```
import csv
import sys
# Count all first-column numbers.
counts = {}
# Loop over all input files.
for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    # Open the file for reading.
    with open(a) as c:
        # Read it as a CSV file.
        reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            count = counts.get(row[0], 0)
            # Increment the count by 1.
            counts[row[0]] = count + 1
# Print only those numbers that have a count of 1.
print([i for i, c in counts.items() if c == 1])
```

Usage:

```
$ python 1.py 1.csv 2.csv
```

output is

```
['51', '21']
```

but i want the output in different row like

```
51
21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line by the following:

```
for result, count in counts.items():
    if count == 1:
        print(result)
```

It's not the most concise way to do it but at least it's quite readable

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the list items on a `\n`:

```
l = ['51', '21']
print("\n".join(l))
```

*Edit:*

In your code (which actually is from an answer I gave you yesterday), do this:

```
print("\n".join([i for i, c in counts.items() if c == 1]))
```